Automatically resize grid elements in order to keep grid inside parent div
Is there a way to automatically resize grid elements to best fill the empty space in a parent div?
I have been using @media queries to deliver different grid parameters for a given screen size which is tedious. Whenever I use auto-fit or auto-fill I have to supply a min value. Selecting a small value may work for small screen resolutions but looks silly at larger screen resolution because the size of the image does not scale up as expected, it simply adds more columns at the small image size. The opposite happens if I use a large min value for bigger screens causing the elements to overflow on mobile etc. See pictures for PC and mobile.
I would like to figure out how to make CSS grid dynamically adjust the number of columns/rows as well as image/tile size to fill the available space inside the parent div as best as possible without @media queries. I think this is possible with CSS grid
Disregard the CSS information for my swiper.
HTML
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo" onclick="window.location.href = 'blah.html';" style="background-image: url('.svg');">
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_000.html';"
                style="background-image: url('000-000.svg');">
                <h3>0</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_001.html';"
                style="background-image: url('001-000.svg');">
                <h3>1</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_002.html';"
                style="background-image: url('002-000.svg');">
                <h3>2</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_003.html';"
                style="background-image: url('003-000.svg');">
                <h3>3</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_004.html';"
                style="background-image: url('004-000.svg');">
                <h3>4</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_005.html';"
                style="background-image: url('005-000.svg');">
                <h3>5</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_006.html';"
                style="background-image: url('006-000.svg');">
                <h3>6</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_007.html';"
                style="background-image: url('007-000.svg');">
                <h3>7</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_008.html';"
                style="background-image: url('008-000.svg');">
                <h3>8</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_009.html';"
                style="background-image: url('009-000.svg');">
                <h3>9</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_010.html';"
                style="background-image: url('010-000.svg');">
                <h3>10</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_011.html';"
                style="background-image: url('011-000.svg');">
                <h3>11</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_012.html';"
                style="background-image: url('012-000.svg');">
                <h3>12</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_013.html';"
                style="background-image: url('013-000.svg');">
                <h3>13</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_014.html';"
                style="background-image: url('014-000.svg');">
                <h3>14</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_015.html';"
                style="background-image: url('015-000.svg');">
                <h3>15</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_016.html';"
                style="background-image: url('016-000.svg');">
                <h3>16</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_017.html';"
                style="background-image: url('017-000.svg');">
                <h3>17</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_018.html';"
                style="background-image: url('018-000.svg');">
                <h3>18</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_019.html';"
                style="background-image: url('019-000.svg');">
                <h3>19</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_020.html';"
                style="background-image: url('020-000.svg');">
                <h3>20</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Click any tile to view assembly steps for selected stage.</h2>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

CSS
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #808080;
}

.colors {
  color: #c0c0c0;
  color: #808080;
  color: #007AFF;
  color: #ff800d;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.main,
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: calc(100vw - 4vh);
}

.main {
  height: calc(100vh - 4vh);
  margin: 2vh;
}

.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 4vh);
  /* margin: 1em; */
  margin-top: 2vh;
  margin-left: 2vh;
  border: solid .1vh black;
  display: flex;
}

.main {
  background: #c0c0c0;
}

.main img,
.wrapper img {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rounded-edges,
img,
.main,
.wrapper,
.wrapper img,
.image,
.mySlider,
.myThumbs img {
  border-radius: 1vh;
}

.shadow,
.mySlider,
img,
.wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/* Swiper -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  /* width: auto; */
  /* height: 100%; */
  object-fit: contain;
}

.mySlider,
.myThumbs {
  position: absolute;
}

.mySlider {
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #c0c0c0;
}

.mySlider img {
  height: 100%;
}

.myThumbs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2vh;
  /* padding-top: 1%; */
  /* padding-bottom: 1%; */
}

/* 
.swiper-slide img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
} */


.myThumbs img {
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border: solid .5vh #c0c0c0;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

/* 
.swiper-slide img {
==  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
} */

.myThumbs .swiper-slide-active img {
  opacity: 1;
  border: solid .5vh #ff800d;
  /* background-color: red; */
  /* object-fit: contain; */
}

/* Navigation ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.index,
.logo {
  height: 4vh;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* justify-content: center; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  position: absolute;
  height: 10vh;
  width: auto;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  content: url('../../template/resources/Prev.svg');
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0vh .5vh 1vh #222);
}

.swiper-button-next {
  content: url('../../template/resources/Next.svg');
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0vh .5vh 1vh #222);
}

.index {
  content: url('../../template/resources/Index-Black.svg');
}

.index:hover {
  content: url('../../template/resources/Index-Orange.svg');
}

.logo {
  /* content: url('../../template/resources/blah-1.svg'); */
}

.logo:hover {
  /* content: url('../../template/resources/blah-2.svg'); */
}

/* Pointer ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.image,
.index,
.logo,
.myThumbs img,
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Justifications ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
.left,
.right,
.top,
.bottom,
.index,
.logo,
h1,
h2,
.swiper-button-prev {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.left,
.index,
.swiper-button-prev {
  left: 2vh;
}

.right,
.logo,
.swiper-button-next {
  right: 2vh;
}

.top,
.index,
.logo,
h1 {
  top: 2vh;
}

.bottom,
h2 {
  bottom: 2vh;
}

/* Swiper Pagination --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.swiper-pagination {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  --swiper-pagination-color: #ff800d;
  --swiper-pagination-progressbar-size: 2vh;
}

/* Opacity ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev,
.index,
.logo,
.image {
  opacity: .8;
}

/* Hover Opacity ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.image:hover,
.swiper-slide img:hover {
  border: solid .5vh #ff800d;
  opacity: 1;
}

.swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Grid ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* .justify { */
/*margin-left: 5vw;*/
/*margin-right: 5vw;*/
/* align-self: center; */
/* width: 90vw; */


.grid {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(7rem, 1fr)); */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: masonry;
    /* grid-template-columns: 1fr; */
  gap: 1rem;
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* max-height: 100%; */
  /* counter-reset: item; */
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  /* padding-left: 4vh; */
  /* padding-right: 4vh; */
}

.image {
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid .5vh black;
}

.image:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(9/16 * 100%);
}

/* Text ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3vh;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5vh;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: .5vh;
  /* margin: auto; */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: .01em;
  text-shadow: 3px 4px 5px #fff;
}

/* Portrait ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  object {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .grid {
    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(11vh, 1fr)); */
  }

  .index,
  .logo {
    height: 3vh;
  }

  h1 {
    margin-top: 4vh;
    font-size: 2vh;
  }

  h3 {
    font-size: 2vh:
  }

  .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next {
    height: 5vh;
  }
}

/* Landscape ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  object {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 4vh;
  }

  .grid {
    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15vw, 1fr)); */
  }
}



Edit
PC

Mobile

Desired distribution that responds to the viewport size / aspect ratio. If this image was flipped to portrait the images would scale down and the columns and rows would adjust to accommodate and fill the available real estate in the parent div without using @media queries. Perhaps one or two @media queries are required for landscape vs portrait but I would like to reduce the number I need to use.



Media queries are unnecessary in this case. The issue is that you are defining the grid columns/gap with vh, which defines the height relative to the size of the browser window. This can lead to overflow when the browser window stretches the height beyond the confines of the wrapper element.
To avoid this, it's best to define things relative to the size of the wrapper element directly. Consider switching out the vh in grid-gap with e.g. rem, and removing grid-template-columns from the media query and defining it with nfr instead of its current value.
EDIT: In response to your comment, here is what the code looks like for me. I simply copied the HTML you posted, added a style tag, then put the CSS you posed into that style tag.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<style>
  body {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #808080;
  }

  .colors {
    color: #c0c0c0;
    color: #808080;
    color: #007AFF;
    color: #ff800d;
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  * img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }

  .main,
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: calc(100vw - 4vh);
  }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo" onclick="window.location.href = 'blah.html';" style="background-image: url('.svg');">
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_000.html';"
                style="background-image: url('000-000.svg');">
                <h3>0</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_001.html';"
                style="background-image: url('001-000.svg');">
                <h3>1</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_002.html';"
                style="background-image: url('002-000.svg');">
                <h3>2</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_003.html';"
                style="background-image: url('003-000.svg');">
                <h3>3</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_004.html';"
                style="background-image: url('004-000.svg');">
                <h3>4</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_005.html';"
                style="background-image: url('005-000.svg');">
                <h3>5</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_006.html';"
                style="background-image: url('006-000.svg');">
                <h3>6</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_007.html';"
                style="background-image: url('007-000.svg');">
                <h3>7</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_008.html';"
                style="background-image: url('008-000.svg');">
                <h3>8</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_009.html';"
                style="background-image: url('009-000.svg');">
                <h3>9</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_010.html';"
                style="background-image: url('010-000.svg');">
                <h3>10</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_011.html';"
                style="background-image: url('011-000.svg');">
                <h3>11</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_012.html';"
                style="background-image: url('012-000.svg');">
                <h3>12</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_013.html';"
                style="background-image: url('013-000.svg');">
                <h3>13</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_014.html';"
                style="background-image: url('014-000.svg');">
                <h3>14</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_015.html';"
                style="background-image: url('015-000.svg');">
                <h3>15</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_016.html';"
                style="background-image: url('016-000.svg');">
                <h3>16</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_017.html';"
                style="background-image: url('017-000.svg');">
                <h3>17</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_018.html';"
                style="background-image: url('018-000.svg');">
                <h3>18</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_019.html';"
                style="background-image: url('019-000.svg');">
                <h3>19</h3>
            </div>
            <div loading="lazy" class="image" onclick="window.location.href = 'Stage_020.html';"
                style="background-image: url('020-000.svg');">
                <h3>20</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Click any tile to view assembly steps for selected stage.</h2>
    </div>
</body>

</html>




I was trying to follow the auto-fit description given here at link which uses fr in its callout.
I moved the .grid entry from the media query to the main definition. I still do not get the expected behaviour. The grid elements overflow and if I set the minmax value small enough for mobile it does not scale up for larger screens.
.grid {   display: grid;   /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(7rem, 1fr)); */   grid-template-columns: 1fr;   gap: 1rem;   max-width: 100%;   max-height: 100%;   margin: auto; }

Okay, thanks for clarifying. I have a better understanding of what you are going for now. I think the issue might be that you are using auto-fit when really the right term might be auto-fill? See the mdn page for repeat() to see an example usage of auto-fill.

I made an edit to my question to show what I am dealing with. Auto-fill is still not giving me the solution I am after. I want the grid to determine the best possible layout / image size to fill the parent div as much as possible without overflowing.

I see. I am trying to reconstruct your code, but the end result looks very different from the images you've posted. Could you please try and put a reproducible example in some HTML with the relevant CSS in a style element (i.e. <style> /* CSS here */ </style>)? (Putting it in a code snippet would be helpful too, but the raw HTML is all I need to reproduce the issue on my own). Once I can reproduce your issue I'll be better able to assist you.

I made a large edit to my question to help illustrate my desired outcome. Hopefully that helps. Thank you for the help.

Thanks for including the HTML. I've tried running it with the CSS. Unfortunately, I still can't reproduce the issue (the view is different on my end, and there is no overflow). But looking at your code, I would guess that the issues might be a result of lazy-loading. My reasoning is this: the CSS is not lazy-loaded, so the grid would be auto-fitting with dimensions of the grid prior to the SVG files loading -- then the SVG files load, and the grid dimensions change, causing overflow. This would also explain why there is no overflow when I run your code (I don't have access to the SVG files).

What does your result look like? Is the html file pointing to the correct location where the CSS file is? I tried removing lazy loading from each div in my html file but I get the same result.

I edited my comment to include a code snippet so you can see what I'm seeing

In your code snippet it you remove the <link line pointing to the css file it will work. Guess you don't need it when building out a code snippet on here.

I removed the link line in my code snippet and it still doesnt seem to be working
